# How to write testcases using Xunit test for extension method like Any

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

Actually this is my service layer. I want to test a create account method by Xunit testing. How can I proceed further?

```cs
public class UserService :IUserService // service
{

    #region Property  
    private readonly IAppDbContext _appDbContext;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor  
    public UserService(IAppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }
     #endregion 

    public int Create(User model)
    {
        _appDbContext.Users.Add(model);
        _appDbContext.SaveChanges();

        return model.Id;
    }

    public  bool CheckAccount(User data)
    {

            

            if (this._appDbContext.Users.Any(x => x.UserName == data.UserName))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public string CheckDetails(User data)
        {
            if (this._appDbContext.Users.Any(x => x.Password == data.Password) &&
                this._appDbContext.Users.Any(x => x.UserName == data.UserName))
            {
                var userid = "";
                var obj = this._appDbContext.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == data.UserName);
                foreach (var i in obj)
                {
                    userid = i.Id.ToString();
                }

                return userid;
            }
            else
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell ,how to I test this method are there in User service by xunit testing

Answer (score 0):

That's simple. You need to use **[Theory]** and **[InlineData]** XUnit attributes.
I prepared a small example for you

```
public class UnitTest
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("First")]
    public void Test1(string productName)
    {
        var productList = new List<Product>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "First"
            },
            new()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Second"
            }
        };

        Assert.True(productList.Any(product => product.Name == productName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , But i want to test entity framework dbset values... could you help me to resolve these problem.. what was i mentioned above.

Comment: Your original question wasn't about EF.

Comment: ok, it about testing Service layer...could you hlp me?